# Call function that is a part of another function with onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a function with a onChange event in HTML. The function is that I am calling is now a part of another function.

When I change the value of the dropdown I dont get any response. The onChange event cant call the function that is in another function.

The script works when I seperate the second function from the first function. But working like that is not an option for me.

Does someone know the right way to call the function with the onChange event?

The onChange event is in line 12.

Here is my script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
    var count = 1;

    $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
      count++;
      $('#total_item').val(count);
      var html_code = '';
      html_code += '<div id="row_id_'+count+'">';
      html_code += '<select name="vat1()" id="vat1'+count+'" onChange="getVat1(this.value)"><option value="0">Test</option><option value="1">Test</option></select>';
      html_code += '</div>';

      $('#test').append(html_code);

    });

    function getVat1() {
      jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: './get/get1.php', 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: {'id' : jQuery('#vat1'+count+'').val()},
        success: function(response){ 
          jQuery('#percentage'+count+'').val(response);
        }, 
        error: function (request, status, error) { 
          alert(request.responseText); 
        }, 
      });                   
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You either have to change `getVat1` to be global scoped, or do not use an inline binding, and instead directly bind on the element

Comment: I changed `onChange="getVat1(this.value)"` to `onChange="getVat1()"`. Also tried `onChange="getVat1"`but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Register the `change` handler with jQuery inside the `ready` handler function. This way, the `onchange` handler can access `getVat1()`.

Above the `$(document).on('click', ...)` write this:

```
$('#test').on('change', '[id^=vat1]', getVat1);
```

Answer (score 0):

your `count` variable is not global so you cant access `count` under your `getVat1()` function  your data will looks like :

```
{'id' : jQuery('#vat1').val()}
```

if you change your code like this, i think it will work(i didnt test) :

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     var count = 1;
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
});


 $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
          count++;
          $('#total_item').val(count);
          var html_code = '';
          html_code += '<div id="row_id_'+count+'">';
          html_code += '<select name="vat1()" id="vat1'+count+'" onChange="getVat1(this.id)"><option value="0">Test</option><option value="1">Test</option></select>';
          html_code += '</div>';

          $('#test').append(html_code);

        });
        function getVat1(id) {
          $.ajax({ 
            url: './get/get1.php', 
            method: 'POST', 
            data: {'id' : $('#'+id).val()},
            success: function(response){ 
            var percantageName = id.Replace("vat1","percentage");
              $('#'+percantageName).val(response);
            }, 
            error: function (request, status, error) { 
              alert(request.responseText); 
            }, 
          });                   
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Still nothing is happening when I change the value of the select element. I also tried to change `id="vat1'+count+'"' to 'id="vat12"` and change `data: {'id' : $('#'+id).val()},` to `data: {'id' : $('#vat12').val()},` but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

Comments added to show how you can bind the local function to the new elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
  var count = 1;

  $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function() {
    //we can increment the count before we set the value to do it in one step
    $('#total_item').val(++count);
    
    //we can construct a new div with jQuery so we can logically bind
    //on the child select.  using template literals makes this much
    //more readable than string concatenation
    //we can also attach the count as a data element so that the event
    //handler has easy access to it
    var $newDiv = $(`
      <div id="row_id_${count}">
        <select name="vat1()" id="vat1${count}" data-count="${count}">
          <option value="0">Test</option>
          <option value="1">Test</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    `);
    
    //finding the select in the div, we can bind the local function to it
    $newDiv.find('select').on('change', getVat1);
    //finally we append the new element to the page
    $('#test').append($newDiv);
  });

  function getVat1( e ) {
    var count = e.target.dataset.count;
    console.log( `Trying to perform an ajax request for count ${count}` );
/* commented out for the StackOverflow answer
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: './get/get1.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        'id': jQuery('#vat1' + count + '').val()
      },
      success: function(response) {
        jQuery('#percentage' + count + '').val(response);
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
      },
    });
*/
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add_row">Add Row</button>
Total Amount: <span id="final_total_amt">20.00</span>
Items: <span id="total_item">1</span>
<div id="test"></div>
```